# Using Sumproduct on array of differences in separate sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

sorry title probably doesn't make sense .. but here is what I am trying to do. I have a list of projects on a sheet with the total number of current hours per project per person. I have another sheet with rates (per person, for different years). Then, I have a sheet of the total project hours on Dec 31 of several years. So the 2017 sheet will include all years up to 17, 2016 sheet all years up to 2016, etc. Right now I am trying to do the 2017 year and I can build up on that to include other years as necessary. Here is what I have and I will try to explain:

```
  =SUMPRODUCT('rates'!B3:'rates'!J3 ,X8-'2017Projects'!B2:AF8-'2017Projects'!J2) + SUMPRODUCT('rates'!B2:'rates'!J2:,'2017Projects'!B2:'2017Projects'!J2)
```

So, what I am trying to do is take the 2017 rates (rates B3-J3) and do a sumproduct of the current years hours minus the hours from the previous year ( current hours in X8- '2017Projects!B2 to cells current AE8 - '2017Projects'!L2') to apply the yearly rate to that years hours. Then, to capture the total here I just do a sumproduct of the 2017 to date hours using the avg rate, but what I'd like to do is similarly sumproduct the difference of the 17/16 hours, then 16/15 hours, etc. It seems like this doesn't work as expected and you cant use sum within a sumproduct. I saw SUMIF, but can't get it to work how I want. Any suggestion for a sumproduct using the difference of 2 arrays? Thanks!

EDIT: btw, I want this to go in a total cost column after the projects hours, didn't include that in sample ..

The calculations I am trying to do are the following:

```
Sum of 
[
    rate b3 * (current hours X8 - 2017Projects B3) [171 * (3.5 - 0)] 
    rate c3 * (current hours Y8 - 2017Projects C3) [214 * (7.5 - 5.25)] 
    rate d3 * (current hours Z8 - 2017projects D3)
    ..etc
]
```

link to sample file: 
https://expirebox.com/download/81ee6c5f8d494097025dd06bf9b404d5.html

Comment: Can you post some sample data? It would make things easier to follow

Comment: `'rates'!B3:'rates'!J3` can be shortened to `'rates'!B3:J3`, both work, just less typing.

Comment: here is a sample worksheet https://www.justbeamit.com/j2pfj. the ws tab has the current hours (starts to the right a bit at w5), then rates and 2017 hours. Let me know if there's a better way to share with you.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but i believe the range you select to be equal in size.  Right now you have B3:J3 (1X9) multiplying with B2:AE8 (7X30).  When I tested 1X8 as one range and a 2X8 as another range it tossed me an error.

Comment: actually i did have a mistake (AE8 should be AF8) but im not sure what you mean about the different sizes (how 7x30?). I will put the calculations I am trying to do in op to be clearer

Comment: Well, with your correction of `AF8` it would be 7X31, that is 7 rows by 31 columns.  Where the range your trying to multiply it by is 1 row by 9 columns.  `SUMPRODUCT` is a powerful tool, but it needs to have a one-to-one correspondence between the elements.

Comment: Well, look at my intentions I guess I am using it wrong that's why I came here, but I am following the docs and previous uses trying to do it in a different way. What I wrote, to me looks like it should do what I want. If i take out the " - 2017PRojects.." part and just have as rates!B3:J3, X8:AF8) it works (that was my previous formula). So, to me what I am trying to do is replace each single cell wth a variable (ie x8 should be x8 - 2017Hours) I simply plugged variables into a working formula. I know it is wrong, but why is this wrong and what other tools do they give that does the same??

Comment: No need to use `SUMPRODUCT`, simple SUM with one to one Multiplication  `sum(B3*Poj!B3,,,)` or `Sum with Range to Range Array formula` will get the correct result. To get more   answers better share sample data with  us.☺

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SUMPRODUCT`, I think an array formula is what you need.

If I understand correctly, you have these arrays that you want to perform mathematical operations on:

`'rates'!B3:J3`  2017 Rates

`X8:AF8`  Current Year hours (cumulative to date with previous years hours)

`'2017Projects'!B3:J3` 2017 hours

And what you want is `2017 Rates` * (`Current Year hours` - `2017 hours`) for each element, and then the sum of all those.

`=SUM('rates'!B3:J3*(X8:AF8-'2017Projects'!B3:J3))`

This is an array formula.  Enter it and then press Ctrl-Shft-Enter.  Your formula should now be enclosed in `{}` brackets.

This subtracts the array `'2017Projects'!B3:J3` from the array `X8:AF8`, one element at a time resulting in a new array with the results of that operation, meaning the first element of that new array will be equal to `X8 - '2017Projects'!B3`, the second element will be `Y8 - '2017Projects'!C3`, and so forth.  That array is then multiplied, one element at a time, with the array `'rates'!B3:J3`. The array resulting from that is then summed.

My system is blocked from your sites so I can't get your files, but let me know if I've missed any important part.